# How can i split a String and use them in a Loop in VB?

Tags: vb.net, string, loops, exchangewebservices, split

i get a string whith email adresses, seperated by a ";" which look like this:

> geve@krag.de;;;Tobias@nxs.de;Wissel@weg.de;Sand@nex.de;Claudia@bea.de;;

i want to send an appointment to these email adresses here a sample to one person:

```
Dim appointment As New EWS.Appointment(esb)
            appointment.Subject = "Einladung zu einem Termin"
            appointment.Body = txtThema.Text
            appointment.Start = Von
            appointment.End = Bis
            appointment.Location = "Raum 202 Kleinostheim"
            appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("geve@krag.de")  // HERE ARE THE Attendees
            appointment.Save(EWS.SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy)
```

i need every email adresses exept the first, becuase he sends the mails. 
how can i do that?

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: i tried nothing i'm still searching

Comment: What do you do with empty ones? Skip them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you would actually split the string into a string array:

```vb
Dim emails As String() = emailString.Split({";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

There are other versions of the overloaded "Split" method, but that particular one lets you to pass in a StringSplitOptions value, allowing you to rule out blank entries right away.

After you have the string array, you can loop through and omit the first one in a few different ways.

We could use a For loop and skip the first entry entirely:

```vb
' Regular For loop approach
Dim emails As String() = emailString.Split({";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim appointment As New EWS.Appointment(esb)
With appointment
    .Subject = "Einladung zu einem Termin"
    .Body = txtThema.Text
    .Start = Von
    .End = Bis
    .Location = "Raum 202 Kleinostheim"             
End With

' start at i = 1 to skip index 0
For i = 1 To emails.Length - 1
    appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(emails(i))  ' HERE ARE THE Attendees
Next

appointment.Save(EWS.SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy)
```

Or identify the sender's email and use a For Each with an If to omit it:

```vb
' For Each approach
' set up string array and appointment object like above

Dim sender As String = emails.FirstOrDefault()

' ignore all instances of the sender's address
For Each address In emails
    If address.ToLower <> sender.ToLower Then
        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(emails(i))  ' HERE ARE THE Attendees
    End If
Next

appointment.Save(EWS.SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy)
```

I'd say play around with it though, and use the approach that best suits you.

Comment: thank you, but there is an error in the first line. it says "Expression expected"

Comment: Is it because "emailString" is not defined? It was just meant to be an example variable for your string of emails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function to parse out each email and use Linq to remove blanks and Skip the first entry.  I think this syntax will work in VB.

```
Dim emailString = "geve@krag.de;;;Tobias@nxs.de;Wissel@weg.de;Sand@nex.de;Claudia@bea.de;;"

Dim emaillist = (From email In emailString.Split(";").Skip(1) Where email.Length > 0 Select email).ToArray()
```

Comment: You don't need the `where` clause if you use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` when you call `.Split`.